# Is $l_{conv}^\infty$ separable?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that this space consist of number sequences $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\ldots)$ that converge.  I thought the answer was yes and we could consider the set of all rational sequences in $l^\infty$ that are $0$ everywhere except finitely many terms.  This would be a countable be its a countable union of sets and therefore countable, but I'm struggling to show density, which is making me question if the space is even separable

Comment: Yes, the space is separable. Your suggestion for a countable dense set is not dense - it's dense in the subspace of sequences that converge to $0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Any hint on how to find one that is dense?

Comment: Your space is just one dimension larger then $c_0$. If $e=(1,1,1,\ldots)$ then $x-\lim x\cdot e\in c_0$. Since you know a dense set in $c_0$, can you do something with this extra $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Say $c_0$ is the space of sequences converging to $0$. Then the space of convergent sequences is just $c_0\times\Bbb K$, where $\Bbb K$ is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, depending on what you mean by "number".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich but how is that countable?  I think we mean $\mathbb{R}$ since this is real analysis

Comment: Of course $c_0\times\Bbb R$ is not countable! If you know a countable dense subset of $c_0$ that allows you to construct a ctounable dense subset of $c_0\times\Bbb R$.

Comment: Not that it matters, but btw you seem to have a misconception regarding what "real anaylsis" is. Note for example that measure theory is certainly a part of real analysis, and in measure theory $L^1(\mu)$ is usually defined as a space of complex-valued functions.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ok so I see how to extend this to all convergent sequences, but I'm still having trouble seeing how the set of all sequences that are $0$ everywhere except finitely many terms is dense in the set of all sequences that converge to $0$.  I know that I need to show that every sequence in sequence that converges to $0$ is a limit point of a seq with rational coefficients that is nonzero at finitely many terms.

Comment: See the deleted answer (I suspect he deleted it when he realized it only applied to $c_0$. But it works for $c_0$...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich How do I do that?  I see here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126348/are-my-deleted-answers-visible-to-others that I need a ton more reputation to see deleted answers

Comment: Say $x\in c_0$ and $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so $|x_j|<\epsilon/2$ for every $j>N$. Let $y=(x_1,\dots,x_N,0,0,\dots)$. Then $||x-y||\le\epsilon/2$. Now find a $z$ in your subset with $||y-z||<\epsilon$..